# Remove "Using your location blue banner" When location popup select "Only while using this app" Option

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager

I just build my app with the iOS 11 SDK using location service. Now my issue is when for app is open then iOS display location alert with three option "**Always Allows**", "**Only while using this app**", and "**Don't allow**"

When user is select "**Only while using this app**" and enter in application.

When user is minimise app then top bar display with "**AppName is actively using your location**"

Now  my question is how to remove top banner ?

Check screen:
[IMAGE HERE](http://prntscr.com/ng3a9t)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Whilst your app, either in the background or foreground uses location services, the device is going to let the user know.

If you don’t need location while the app is in the background, inside your AppDelgate you can pause the listener inside the `applicationWillEnterBackground` and then restart it when the user reopens the app inside `applicationWillEnterForeground`

Answer (score 0):

When user select `Only while using this app` don't take location in the background just by doing this

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false
```

By doing this it will not show the blue bar when your app went in background.

P.S you can set allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true if you have the permission of  `Always Allows`.

Comment: @Bhavensh, please check the answer?